# The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context in a standalone class

Tags: c#, asp.net

i try to use the following code to initialize an ApplicationManager

```
public static ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {

        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

but unfortunately i got an error says `The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context`
ps: i'm initializing this ApplicationManager in a standalone class.

Comment: Where did you copy that code from? Wherever that was it had a `Request` property. I suspect you copied it from a Controller. It could have been a WebForms page too, their base class also has a Request property

Comment: You can access the Request from the [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Since you made that property static you are forced to use HttpContext's singleton instance through HttpContext.Current. This will result in untestable code. How are you going to test `UserManager` if you can't create a dummy HttpContext in your tests? You should probably rethink your static classes and properties. They make things *harder*

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.Request` is this what you are looking for??